# What is an alernative for the form select for full versatility in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-select

I know Internet Explorer has always been hopeless with styling html `<select>` with inconsistent or non-existent font sizes, colours, borders, background colours etc so what are some alternatives for creating your own flexible field that is cross-browser compatible?

It's fine to require any JavaScript framework such as jQuery etc. I'm thinking a simply CSS menu almost acts fine as an alternative, with the "menu item" selected being added to a hidden field...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why replace a perfectly functional native select box with keyboard navigation and all the good stuff for a homemade hackish solution that will make your site inaccessible for users with Javascript turned off or screen readers? If 99.9% of websites can manage to make their select boxes blend in, you should really just suck it up and style it as much as you can.

You could however look into [this jQuery plugin](http://www.headcircus.com/uiguy/selectboxfactory/selectboxfactory.html) which enhances select boxes in different ways.

Comment: Fair enough comment, but the limited styling options does entice you to look at alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I guess drop down menu will do it easily with a hidden field as a data holder. Don't see any potential problems... well, except if JavaScript is turned off.